# border-radius в button

Tags: html, css

Почему если написать

```
border-radius: 5;
```

ничего не произойдёт, а если добавить `px` то углы изменятся.

почему в `border-radius` надо писать `px`, а в `height` и `width` не надо?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .btn1{
                width: 100;
            }
            .btn2{
                width: 100px;
            } 
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button class="btn1" >btn1</button>
        <button class="btn2" >btn2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: коли утверждаете, что писать не надо для ширины высоты, то приведите воспроизводимый  пример.

Comment: "Почему небо голубое?! "

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units

Comment: Кроме ваших стилей есть ещё стили  браузера и стили подключаемые различными плагинами - именно поэтому у Вас кнопки одинаковой ширины, что с `px`, что без. Если бы на них ничего не воздействовало больше, кроме ваших стилей, то `.btn1` была бы меньше.

Comment: @UModeL спасибо понял, но почему с `border-radius` так не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если писать css код, то **width** и **height** тоже требуют указания **px** как и **border-radius**. Так указано в спецификаций CSS. Если указать без **px** не будет работать [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

[MDN о border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

[MDN о width](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/width)

Comment: Требуют добавить единицы измерения, но не обязательно `px`